# How to share desktop over LAN to multiple viewers

Tags: windows-7, vnc

I need to share one machine's screen to 10 computers in the same LAN, without internet.
The platform is Windows 7.
I've tried Windows remote desktop help but only allows one viewer.
I'm testing UltraVNC but is kind of slow.

I have limitations, I'm using a wireless-N network at 150Mbps.

**Update**:

The use-case is for teaching how to use software or to share a presentation to the viewers.
The streaming with VLC didn't work. Great article anyway, I'll test it again in other opportunity.
LogmeIn and teamviewer required internet to sign in, so I couldn't test those.
Tuning UltraVNC a bit worked fine, but not as good as I needed.
It's true that a projector will do the trick but my client doesn't want one.

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to share the display?  Are you trying to transmit HD video, some kind of MS Office training, something else?  When you say VNC is slow, are you talking about latency, or does your application actually not look good?

Comment: possibly http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/

Comment: If UltraVNC is a bit slow try some of the other VNC implementations.

Answer (score 8):

You can stream your desktop using [vlc](http://www.videolan.org) in conjunction with the `screen://` input access module (gets screenshots from the primary screen) as a (multicast) streaming server and then use vlc again on the desktops as a client. There is a fair number of walkthroughs on the net for this, here is an example of a rather decent one:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150412221024/http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14625

Answer (score 4):

I would go for Teamviewer as it allows a presentation mode and works in lan-only environments.

Check [www.teamviewer.com](http://www.teamviewer.com)

Not sure if this is available in the free version though...

Comment: It is still available in the free version of team Viewer 10

Answer (score 3):

**STATUS: Resolved**

I found an excellent, ultra-small application that does exactly what I need: [ScreenStream](http://www.nchsoftware.com/screen/index.html).

(have to run with compatibility mode)

Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are RealVNC will work alright for you if the source machine has decent specs; it might be slow for the first minute while it caches, and in general remote desktop works badly for sharing video and animations, but it should be usable.

If you find it is latent and choppy, you could always try reducing the resolution and colour settings, and make sure you're not sharing sound or other things besides just the display.

Lotus notes sametime also has a meeting feature we use semi-regularly to show presentations to hundreds of users at one organization I am with... but it works much better for slideshows than demonstrations.

You may find you get better ROI from a simple data projector.

Answer (score 1):

Tight Projector is really great solution though not free.
It allows streaming to multiple clients using UDP multicast, so the streaming pc will not be burdened by multiple clients, it will still send only single packets received by all viewers.

http://www.tightprojector.com/